# Esami package - reducing space between answers in a multiple choice test

Tags: packages, esami

I would like to reduce the space between different answers in a multiple choice test. Here is my code:

```
\newproblem{
\fbox{%
\parbox{\textwidth}{%
\item In base ai principi della dinamica, in un sistema inerziale, un corpo soggetto a forze la cui risultante è costante nel tempo e diversa da zero
\begin{answers}{1}\bChoices[random]
\Ans0 aumenta la sua velocità \eAns
\Ans0 varia costantemente la sua accelerazione \eAns
\Ans1 cambia il suo vettore velocità \eAns
\Ans0 mantiene costante la sua velocità\eAns
\eChoices\end{answers} 
  }%
 }    
}
```

And here is the result:
[image]

I would like the lines (a), (b), (c), (d) to be closer to each other. Is it possible?

Comment: It _is_ possible but I don't think it is better.

Comment: I need to maximize the number of questions per paper sheet

Comment: You are going to sacrifice readability, which will make the test unduly more hard for some students.

Answer (score 1):

To set the space among answers as you desire, you can try with different values of the parameters `\rowsepDefault` and `\aboveanswersSkip` in the master file of your exam.
As an example, in our exams we have the following settings:

```
\rowsepDefault{4pt}
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{2pt} 
\addtolength{\arraycolsep}{2pt}
\setlength\aboveanswersSkip{6pt}
```